# Cucumber for Rails - unresolved specs errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber

I'm trying to add cucumber to an existing rails app.  I was able to do the initial rails generator cucumber:install step and did a --help check to confirm it was there.  But when I try to run cucumber from the windows cmd, I get a list of gem unresolved specs warnings and I don't get the expected output regarding features ran etc.  Please see attached pic and please let me know if you can help me understand the root cause.  Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Those are not errorrs. They are Warnings. Shouldn't stop the execution of your app.

Comment: True, but they are the only thing I can think of that is keeping cucumber from giving me the list of number of features etc at the end, so I'm treating them like errors for now until I figure out the root cause. Thanks.